# terraform how to describe variable type with changing keys in object

Tags: terraform

I've got an ever changing list of objects as variable and wanted to know how to properly describe its type

```sh
variable "lifecycle_rules" {
  type = set(object({
#    set(object({
#      action = map(string)
#      condition = map(string)
#    }))
  }))
  default = [
    {
    first = [
      {
        condition = {
          age = "1"
        }
        action = {
          type = "Delete"
        }
      },
      {
        condition = {
          age = "2"
        }
        action = {
          type = "Delete"
        }
      }
    ]},
    {
     second = [
      {
        condition = {
          age = "3"
        }
        action = {
          type = "Delete"
        }
      },
      {
        condition = {
          age = "4"
        }
        action = {
          type = "Delete"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Here should be line with smth like this `string = set(object({...`
the first and second are always changing, so `key` value should be
string but can't really set it - any other thoguhts, how to write
type for the default below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I think the correct one is:

```
  type = set(
      map(
        set(
          object({condition = map(string), 
                  action    = map(string)})
           )
       )
     )
```

In the `map` you don't specify attributes, as they can be different. In the most inner one you have `object` as `condition` and `action` are constant.